# How to look for overlaps in time - Javascript and moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs

I'm building a calendar in which I am adding events in a day to an array

The time stamp for startTime and endTime is stored in String format
Example for Events in a day

```js
const events = [{
    "_id": "5bdf91a78197f0ced6c03496",
    "user": "5bd62237d62cc34a29e93c46",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "date": "2018-11-04",
    "startTime": "16:00",
    "endTime": "17:00",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bdf91ec8197f0ced6c03497",
    "patient": "5bd62237d62cc34a29e93c46",
    "firstName": "Punith",
    "lastName": "Ch",
    "date": "2018-11-04",
    "startTime": "17:00",
    "endTime": "18:00",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bdf91ec8197f0ced6c03498",
    "patient": "5bd62237d62cc34a29e93c46",
    "firstName": "Punith",
    "lastName": "Ch",
    "date": "2018-11-04",
    "startTime": "06:00",
    "endTime": "07:00",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

When a user makes a new request to create I need to check whether it overlaps with any of current events

Post data is

```js
{
  "patient": "5bd62237d62cc34a29e93c46",
  "firstName": "Punith",
  "lastName": "Ch",
  "date": "2018-11-04",
  "startTime": "15:00",
  "endTime": "16:21",
  "__v": 0
}
```

I like to throw an error message to use if it overlaps
Library's in use moment, lodash

My code looks as below

```js
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
      const events = axios.get('/getEvents?date=2018-11-04') // gets array of appointments

      //const event to be added 
      const eventToBeAdded = req.body

      //need to have logic here to check the overlapping
      function checkoverlap(events, eventToBeAdded) return true or false

      if (false) {
        res.status(422).json('Event overlaps with other')
        }
        res.status(201).json('created')
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the startTime and endTime and iterate through the sorted list and check if the endTime of the current array is greater than the startTime of the next one.

```js
const events = [{
        "_id": "5bdf91a78197f0ced6c03496",
        "user": "5bd62237d62cc34a29e93c46",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "date": "2018-11-04",
        "startTime": "12:00",
        "endTime": "14:00",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bdf91ec8197f0ced6c03497",
        "patient": "5bd62237d62cc34a29e93c46",
        "firstName": "Punith",
        "lastName": "Ch",
        "date": "2018-11-04",
        "startTime": "17:00",
        "endTime": "18:00",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bdf91ec8197f0ced6c03498",
        "patient": "5bd62237d62cc34a29e93c46",
        "firstName": "Punith",
        "lastName": "Ch",
        "date": "2018-11-04",
        "startTime": "15:00",
        "endTime": "20:00",
        "__v": 0
    }
];

function checkOverlap(timeStart, timeEnd) {
    const data = events;
    let start = [];
    data.forEach((e) => {
        let d = [e.startTime, e.endTime];
        start.push(d);
    });
    // sorted the time
    start.sort();
    start.forEach((e, i) => {
        if (start[i + 1]) {
            if (e[1] > start[i + 1][0]) {
              console.log(e.join(' ') + " overlap");
            }
        }
    });
}

checkOverlap();
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is check wheter the start or end of `eventToBeAdded` is in between the start and end of one of the events. You could check that by comparing the timestamp.

```
function checkoverlap(events, eventToBeAdded) {
    var addedStart = new Date(eventToBeAdded.date + " " + eventToBeAdded.startTime).getTime();
    var addedEnd = new Date(eventToBeAdded.date + " " + eventToBeAdded.endTime).getTime();

    for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
        var eventStart = new Date(events[i].date + " " + events[i].startTime).getTime();
        var eventEnd = new Date(events[i].date + " " + events[i].endTime).getTime();

        if ((addedStart > eventStart && addedStart < eventEnd) || (addedEnd > eventStart && addedEnd < eventEnd)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it checks date 
I can only add one event on a single with this logic - all other events even though they are not overlapping it will return false

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please clarify?

Comment: so as per your logic I can add one event per day. when I'm trying to add second event in the same day checkoverlap function returns true - so I cant add any event on that particular day

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's not checking by date, but I wrongly write the conditions in if statement. Fixed it so that it checks whether the start or end time of `eventToBeAdded` is in between the start and end time of one of the events

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment().isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/).

In my understanding it'll be a loop like this :

```
checkoverlap = (events, eventToBeAdded) =>{
  events.forEach(oldEvent => {
  if(moment(eventToBeAdded.startTime).isBetween(oldEvent.startTime, oldEvent.endTime) 
  || moment(eventToBeAdded.endTime).isBetween(oldEvent.startTime, oldEvent.endTime))
    return true;
  })
return false;
}
```